# How to convert from one by one to a mass output using PHP

Tags: php, twitter

I am trying to find a way how to get the twitter ID from a list of users. I found the following link that works pretty well, you just replace ABC with the username you want

```
http://www.idfromuser.com/getID.php?username=ABC
```

What you get is the id from that user. Using "View Page Source" there is only the ID, no format or stuff.

What I want to do and do not know how, is how can I load a list of usernames and get/save the IDs. No one by one.

Thank you. I have a knowledge in PHP

**Update**
I have a list of usernames saved in a .txt file. The output with the IDs may be printed or screen or saved in a txt. I know that this is a solution with a *get file contents* but I need some guide/example

Comment: Who are the users? How will you know their usernames? And where do you want to save the ID's to? Please be more specific

Comment: @JanisPeisenieks I have updated the question. The users are saved in a txt file and are my colleagus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use the [`twitter API`](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api)?

This returns the `user ID`along with other details

```
GET  https://api.twitter.com/1/users/lookup.jsonscreen_name=ABC&include_entities=true
```

> Return up to 100 users worth of extended information, specified by
>   either ID, screen name, or combination of the two. The author's most
>   recent status (if the authenticating user has permission) will be
>   returned inline.

It's pretty powerful, with only two requests you can get as much as 200 user ID's max.

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/users/lookup

---

It is better you concatenate (comma-separated) as much as 100 user ID's to the lookup URL, because it would return a max of 100 for each query. Unauthenticated users are rate limited so:

Example Code:

```
$lookupString = ""; //usernames seperated by new line character in text file

foreach ($notf as $key => $value) {
    $lookupString .= $value.",";   //concatenating, comma separated.
}

$lookupStringUrl = "http://api.twitter.com/1/users/lookup.json?user_id=".$lookupString;

$namejson = json_decode(file_get_contents($lookupStringUrl));

foreach ($namejson as $key => $value) {
    echo $value->id."\n";
}
```

Comment: @Kaoukkos You're welcome! If you run into problems, come back here!

Comment: Dear Mob, Now this code is not working. The Twitter REST API v1 is no longer active. Please migrate to API v1.1. Need to upgrade.